# Magento - 404 only in edit/section/dev/

Tags: magento

I'm having some trouble entering my Configuration>Advanced>Developer section to enable the profiler ex. when this www.sitename.com/index.php/system_config/edit/section/dev/ URL is loaded, I get a 404 error. I've checked through all my logs, no clue on why this is happening?

How could I trace the source of the problem? - no clues in logs. And it's on a live site, it's been a long time since I've last used this part of Magento, so I don't know if anything was installed or changed that could have provoked this, sadly.

Comment: Which 404 page are you seeing? http://alanstorm.com/magentos_many_404_pages

Comment: This: http://alanstorm.com/2011/img/404-article/exception.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're seeing a 404 page with the Admin UI/Chrome, and 404 text in the content area,  this sounds like your user account doesn't have Access Control Permissions to view the developer section of the system configuration.

**Update**: Based on information in the comments above, it sounds like some custom code (or possible core code reacting to something incorrect in the system) is throwing a `Mage_Core_Model_Store_Exception` exception.  If you open up the `app/Mage.php` file, look for this catch block.

```
#File: app/Mage.php
} catch (Mage_Core_Model_Store_Exception $e) {
    require_once(self::getBaseDir() . DS . 'errors' . DS . '404.php');
    die;
}
```

This is where the 404 page you're seeing is included.  Try adding some temporary debugging code — something like this

```
} catch (Mage_Core_Model_Store_Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
    //or
    var_dump($e);
    require_once(self::getBaseDir() . DS . 'errors' . DS . '404.php');
    die;
}
```

to dump the contents of the exception message, or the entire exception itself.  This will show you the error Magento's encountering that's forcing it to show the 404 page, which should help you track down your problem.

Comment: Yes I've tried to add my user to another role where I manually set the rights to use the developer menu, instead of just choosing the all from admin. But It's still doing the same, maby the permissions is broken somewhere? Got to see if I can reset them somehow

Comment: @ThomasNielsen That is, I **updated** the answer with debugging information.

Comment: Thank's @AlanStorm but all i get from the debugging snippet, if I use the first part before //or is (  string(0) ""  ) and if I use the second part, I get such a large exception that my browsers crashes :(

Comment: @ThomasNielsen Ah, most Magento developers I know use xDebug, so that takes care of the "exception too large" problem.  In order to work around that, take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php.  There's a list of exception methods there for extracting information from an exception object (`getMessage`, `getCode`, etc.) You can use these to track the exception to its source, which is turn can help reveal why it was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @AlanStorm - That got me this far:

I used this snippet:

```
} catch (Mage_Core_Model_Store_Exception $e) {
                 var_dump($e->getTraceAsString());
```

```
0/var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(831): Mage_Core_Model_App->throwStoreException() 
1/var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php(342): Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore('4') 
2/var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php(616): Mage_Core_Model_Url->setStore('4') 
3/var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php(734): Mage_Core_Model_Url->setRouteParams(Array, false) 
4/var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php(977): Mage_Core_Model_Url->getRouteUrl('', Array) 
5/var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/local/ManaPro/FilterSeoLinks/Model/Url.php(18): Mage_Core_Model_Url->getUrl('', Array) 
6/var/www/site.com/public_html/app/Mage.php(362): ManaPro_FilterSeoLinks_Model_Url->getUrl('', Array) 
7/var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/local/Magentohotel/Varnish/Model/Adminhtml/Renderer/Bans/Categories.php(31): Mage::getUrl('', Array) 
8/var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(421): Magentohotel_Varnish_Model_Adminhtml_Renderer_Bans_Categories->toOptionArray(true) 
9/var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(210): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initFields(Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element)) 
10/var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Edit.php(92): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initForm() 
11/var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php(102): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Edit->initForm() 
12/var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController->editAction()    
13/var/www/site.com/public_html/var/cache/extendware/ewcore/overrides/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard/63563f9ebb198e3182fd11a84369b608.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit') 
14/var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_StandardOverriddenClass->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http)) 
15/var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(348): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() 
16/var/www/site.com/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
17/var/www/site.com/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store') 
18{main}"
```

And when I disabled the Magentohotel Varnish module, I could yet again enter the developer section! I really appreciate your help @AlanStorm thank you. I'm not developer so I'm not all in to xDebug and such :) but I'm trying my best